# multiple requestparam in springboot pageable

Tags: spring-boot, restful-url, http-request-parameters, pageable

i know that this question may be duplicated but i tried a lot with no success

I need to make multiple RequestParam in spring boot rest controller as following :

```
@GetMapping("/prd-products/test")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<List<Test>> getAllTests(@RequestParam (required = false) String search, @RequestParam (required = false) Pageable pageable) {
    Page<Test> page = prdProductsService.findAllTest(search, pageable);
    HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(page, "/api/prd-products");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(page.getContent(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

when i try to call this service by url like :

```
http://localhost:9116/api/prd-products/test?search=id==1,id==2&pageable=0&size=2
```

it give me following error

```
"title": "Bad Request",
"status": 400,
"detail": "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable': no matching editors or conversion strategy found",
```

when i try to send one request param it successfully work .

Note : id==1,id==2 is the way that fields is parsed in search

Comment: Are you using Spring Data Rest? Your url doesn't seems like the pattern which Spring Data Rest works by default..

Comment: yes i work with spring rest , can you provide me with the default pattern you mean ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With Spring Boot you can just register [PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/web/PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html) bean

```
@Bean
public PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableResolver() {
    return new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
}
```

In controller

```
public ResponseEntity<List<Test>> getAllTests(
    @RequestParam (required = false) String search,
    @PageableDefault(page = 0, size = 100) Pageable pageable
) {
    ...
}
```

And then adjust your query parameters to 
`...&page=0&size=2`

Answer (score 2):

Spring cannot convert a String to a Pageable. You should create a Pageable object from the request parameters, for example, with [PageRequest.of](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html#of-int-int-).

Example:

```java
@GetMapping("/prd-products/test")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<List<Test>> getAllTests(
        @RequestParam (required = false) String search,
        @RequestParam (required = false) Integer pageIndex,
        @RequestParam (required = false) Integer pageSize) {
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageIndex, pageSize);
    Page<Test> page = prdProductsService.findAllTest(search, pageable);
    HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(page, "/api/prd-products");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(page.getContent(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: it works correctly , but in my way i sent before why it accepts pageable when i sent it alone with no other request param ?

Comment: The only parameter you were sending to make it work was the `pageable`, or the `search` ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how it is capable of creating a `Pageable` object from a single request parameter named `pageable`.

Answer (score 0):

Your QueryString seems strange.

In order to use Spring Data REST to create and inject a Pageable, you need to do something like this:

`?page=0&size=2&ids=1,2`

Your REST Controller:

```java
public ResponseEntity <List<Test>> getAllTests(@RequestParam(required = false) String search, @RequestParam(required = false) Pageable pageable) {
    Page<Test> page = prdProductsService.findAllTest(search, pageable);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(page.getContent(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

This way, Spring Data REST will create a Pageable object.

See [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.1.10.RELEASE/reference/html/#repository-resources.query-method-resource).

Comment: i cannot make list of ids because search String is a dynamic way to search , it accepts any property of the entity and any operation not only == , it must be in a dynamic way

Comment: no it give me the same error , this what i did before

Comment: You sure you're using Sprint DATA REST? <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId><artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>